# Ubuntu only booting in discrete graphics mode (GTX 1070)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia, uefi, intel-graphics

I have installed Ubuntu several times on my old notebook and everything always worked fine. Now I have a new one:

- Schenker H507 (CLEVO P65-67RSRP) with G-Sync Display
- Intel Core i7 6700HQ
- Intel HD 530
- NVIDIA GTX 1070
- Crucial Balistix Sport 32GB DDR4 2400Mhz RAM

On this Notebook I have a SAMSUNG 960 Pro SSD with Windows 10 running in UEFI mode.
Now I wanted to install Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.1 LTS on my second SSD (SAMSUNG 850 Pro).

My Problem is that only if I turn on Discrete Mode in BIOS, which is for exclusively using the NVIDIA GTX 1070 graphics and shutting off Intel HD 530, I can boot into Ubuntu and install it.

[Here is a picture taken after installation in UEFI mode with only discrete graphics activated.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vunzn.jpg)

I already tried many several solutions provided on Ask Ubuntu, but they all did not work for me. With HD 530 activated either I got a black screen or stuck at loading screen or a flickering screen.

I can install Ubuntu in **Legacy Mode** with both graphics cards activated, but I can not convert Ubuntu Legacy into UEFI mode.

`lshw` output of display in Legacy Mode:

```
*-display UNCLAIMED
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: NVIDIA Corporation
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: a1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                resources: memory:db000000-dbffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:dc000000-dc07ffff

*-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 06
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915_bpo latency=0
             resources: iomemory:2f0-2ef irq:127 memory:2ffe000000-2ffeffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

Can someone help me please? I also tried Ubuntu 16.10. Currently I have Ubuntu installed in UEFI mode with only GTX 1070 activated. I do not want to turn off HD 530 every time I boot Ubuntu.

Comment: My Skylake system is Intel only but I installed this: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/intel-linux-graphics-firmwares but I still get message on possible missing kbl version which is just for Kabylake. the dmc file was same version as I already had, but I installed skl/GuC version.

Comment: i tried to install this and activate my Intel again but it did not work

Comment: Generally it should work using this solution -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/871978/trying-to-install-ubuntu-results-in-freezing-splash-screen-nomodeset-did-not-w/872160#872160 ! Alternatively set the boot parameter `nomodeset` instead of `nouveau.modeset=0` ... in case that you are facing the other errors (beside the `nouveau` error) shown in your screenshot ! :)

Comment: should I install ubuntu with these tags or try to boot my already installed ubuntu with these? Should I install the nvidia drivers? They keep saying 16.10 version of ubuntu, should I use this?

Comment: No matter which of the both flags i add at the end of  the Linux line (without changing anything else) I just get a purple screen After pressing F10. But when I press the on/off Button my notebook shuts down with the ubuntu loading Icon

Comment: When I try Them with my installer then nomodeset brings a Black screen and nouveau just brings the loading ubuntu Icon which gets one Time Full then stays like this

Comment: Eventually there is a hardware issue ? Maybe you contact the SCHENKER or TUXEDO Computers support. As I said in my answer : They ship their machines with Ubuntu preinstalled, so it should work somehow. :)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @cl-netbox I got the solution. If you already have Ubuntu installed in Discrete mode do this:

> Open a Terminal and use this command:
>
> `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
>
> put between this:
>
> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="[...]
> ```
>
> and this:
>
> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
> ```
>
> the following:
>
> ```
> GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1920*1080
> ```
>
> Save it with Ctrl+O and exit STRG+X. Then:
>
> ```
> sudo update-grub
> ```
>
> if its on the PC then open
>
> ```
> sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-dpms.conf
> ```
>
> Put in front of each row a "#" Save it with Ctrl+O and exit STRG+X.
>   Then try to reboot in DISCRETE again if every thing works. MSHYBRID
>   Should now work.

How to use MSHYBRID in the Installer:

> If you want to have it right in Install working the use MSHYBRID, to boot to >the Ubuntu USB. Highlight "Install Ubuntu" and press "E"  One Row above "Linux
>   /casper...." put
>
> ```
> set gfxpayload=1920*1080
> ```
>
> and start installation with F10. After Install use "Crtl+ALT+F1" to go
>   to Terminal log in. Do the above steps to enable Booting in MSHYBRID
>   mode.

source: https://www.linux-onlineshop.de/forum/index.php?page=Thread&threadID=385

Otherwise if you have a Clevo Notebook install Ubuntu in Discrete Mode like this:
https://www.tuxedocomputers.com/TUXEDO-WebFAI.geek
And then do the above steps.

Comment: Yeah right... pff!

Comment: Only `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1920*1080` was required for Ubuntu 17.10 (50-dpms.conf file is empty).

Why is it needed at all, and what we should fix to make it work out of the box?