# Ubuntu 18.04 stopped working with NVIDIA drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on a CLEVO notebook and have the nvida-390 drivers and Cuda installed. It worked fine for a month, but - suddenly today it stopped working. I can still access the login screen, but the screen remains purple.

I've already tried to purge and reinstall the nvidia-390 drivers (I've also tried the 396 drivers version) without success. After the login the computer always stops working. I cannot even access tty. After purging the drivers I can login and all works fine with `nouveau`, but I really need Cuda for my work.

My specs:

- i7-6700HQ
- 8GB RAM
- Nvidia GeForce GTX 970M
- Intel Wireless 8260

Can someone please help me? Thanks.

Comment: Try booting an old kernel

Comment: Please try out whether booting with the parameter `nvidia-drm.modeset=1` solves the problem. :)

Comment: @cl-netbox it worked!! Thank you! Please answer the question so i can give you the actual right answer :)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You might need to have **D**irect **R**endering **M**anager Kernel Mode Setting **enabled** on system boot.
NVIDIA driver's PRIME Synchronization support relies on DRM-KMS, which is disabled by default.
Find more comprehensive information in the [discussion](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/957814/linux/prime-and-prime-synchronization/) on the NVIDIA GPU Unix Graphics forum.

Execute `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` and add the parameter `nvidia-drm.modeset=1` to the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. Save the change you've made and run `sudo update-grub`.
Restart the Ubuntu operating system, and now everything should work properly, right as expected.

Comment: Congrats on bounty you deserve it :)

Comment: Once I do this, the monitor running on NVidia will block on "Starting Gnome DISPLAY Manager" however the other monitor is fine. Remove the modeset from GRUB then all is fine, except screen tearing on NVidia. Any ideas how to diagnose or fix ?

Comment: @abdelrahman-sinno Without knowing any further details providing you with a correctly working solution is not possible. I suggest that you ask a new question including as much information as possible about your specific hardware and system setup and about what you have already tried so far to solve the problem. :)

Comment: @cl-netbox I have posted my question here (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093409/nvidia-gt-710-screen-tearing-on-18-04-horizontal-lines-in-videos), please let me know if you need any further info

Comment: didn't work  for me

Comment: This solution works perfectly for my problem of Ubuntu 18.04 booting to blank screen with Nvidia GPU and drivers installed. My machine is Alienware 15.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Ubuntu 18.04 - GM108M [GeForce 940MX]

Comment: This is the only thing that made horizontal tearing disappear on Plasma 5 on nVidia.

Comment: Worked great for me! (Ubuntu version 20.04 LTS/GTX 1070). Thanks a lot!

Comment: this worked for me, what you need to do is "enroll MOK" in the bootscreen and enroll the key and enter the password you set for UEFI Secure Boot (or whatever it's called). After doing this step I was able to see both displays are claimed.

Comment: Another alternative that did not work for me. Now I cannot even purge nvdia and go back to default

Comment: works for me. had the same issue with 20.04. (found many threads suggesting to reinstalling drivers, but that didn't work at all).

Comment: This was perfect. I am using Xubuntu 18.04 with a GTX 1050 Mobile. This made the annoying screen tearing disappear in XFCE. I even stopped using Compton and went back to using the default compositor of XFCE.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get it working with the latest Nvidia-418 drivers on a Lenovo W530 with the Nvidia GK107GLM Quadro K2000M:

1. Edit the `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` and remove "quiet splash" from GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and then `sudo update-grub` *(that may be similar then adding `nvidia-drm.modeset=1`)*
2. Switch to LightDM: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` *(necessary so my second monitor was recognized)*
3. Install PPA with latest drivers: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` and `sudo apt-get update`
4. Install latest recommended driver (in my case Nvidia 418): `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`