# Nvidia GT 710 screen tearing on 18.04 (horizontal lines in videos)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, graphics, multiple-monitors

I have a 2-monitor setup on my **18.04**, one on the internal Intel GPU, and the second screen via DVI-D running on **NVIDIA GT 710** card, while I have the latest **415 NVIDIA driver**.
When watching videos on the NVIDIA-connected monitor, I get horizontal lines that keep moving up-and-down the video, I believe it's called screen tearing.

I have attempted proposed solutions, such as setting `nvidia-drm.modeset=1` to the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`, but then the NVIDIA monitor will block on '*Starting Gnome DISPLAY Manager*' during boot, while the other monitor logs in fine; then in *Displays* configuration I don't see the second monitor anymore.

**Update:** Intel monitor is tearing as well, although a little less.

Running `xrandr --verbose` returns the following (filtered for relevance):

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1200, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-D-0 connected 1920x1200+1920+0 (0x46) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
    Identifier: 0x2b1
    Timestamp:  148801474
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       1
    CRTCs:      1 2 3 4
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
    BorderDimensions: 4 
        supported: 4
    Border: 0 0 0 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    SignalFormat: TMDS 
        supported: TMDS
    ConnectorType: DVI-D 
    ConnectorNumber: 0 
    _ConnectorLocation: 0 
  1920x1200 (0x46) 154.000MHz +HSync -VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  74.04KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1203 end 1209 total 1235           clock  59.95Hz
  1920x1080 (0x2b2) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
DP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1200+0+0 (0x46) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
    Identifier: 0x42
    Timestamp:  148801426
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:     HDMI-1-1
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0 5 6
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    PRIME Synchronization: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
  1920x1200 (0x46) 154.000MHz +HSync -VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  74.04KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1203 end 1209 total 1235           clock  59.95Hz
  1920x1080 (0x47) 148.500MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
DP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x44
    Timestamp:  148801426
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 5 6
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    PRIME Synchronization: 1 
        supported: 0, 1
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
  1920x1200 (0x46) 154.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  74.04KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1203 end 1209 total 1235           clock  59.95Hz
```

Comment: You are using unstable beta drivers, but regardless this fact, what makes me wonder is : DP-1-1 connected -> PRIME Synchronization: 0 (=off) | DP-1-2 disconnected -> PRIME Synchronization: 1 (=on) ... so please check the configuration settings in the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file - in case it exits. Maybe something is not set up correctly, the way it should be. I have upvoted your question to raise the attention / attraction ! :)

Comment: Thanks however `/etc/X11/xorg.conf ` doesn't exist. I have tried the non-beta 410 driver and it behaves the same way.

Comment: Suggestion : Remove all currently installed NVIDIA drivers and software. Install the latest stable **original unmodified** [NVIDIA drivers 410.78](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/140135/en-us) ... follow exactly the instructions provided in the [Installation Guide](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/410.78/README/index.html). :)

Comment: @cl-netbox I have already done this, however I need help with these instructions [Multiple Displays](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/410.78/README/configtwinview.html). What happens is that setting HorizSync and VertRefresh is causing one display to have a limited low resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue here. I found some of solution, maybe this helped

## 1. edit this file (or create it)

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/zz-nvidia-modeset.conf
```

## 2. and add this line

> options nvidia_drm modeset=1

## 3. after all, update initramfs with

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

## 4. then reboot.

Source: https://www.cmscritic.com/stop-screen-tearing-with-optimus-laptops-using-nvidia-drivers-in-linux/

Comment: Unfortunately, for me this causes the NVIDIA-connected monitor to stop working; instead it is stuck showing boot log message "Started GNOME Display Manager." The other monitor works normally in this case

Comment: Your external monitor problem is due to using gdm3. Install lightdm or if you have installed it do sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm. Either way make lightdm your default display manager. Reboot and problem fixed. gdm3 and modeset=1 don't work together.