# Deepin/Ubuntu white/black screen on login/lock pages (particularly with Deepin greeter)

Tags: nvidia, login, lightdm

I recently encountered an issue with the Deepin lightdm greeter that I'd like to elaborate an answer on, as finding it is a little obscure and this would, hopefully, help anyone searching around.

The same issue is found on [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048274/ubuntu-18-04-stopped-working-with-nvidia-drivers). I'd comment, but I don't have 50 rep!

When using the proprietary Nvidia drivers, you may come across an issue where your login screen / lock screen come up as black or white, maybe with an icon. This occurred for me with the deepin lightdm greeter. As an initial workaround, I switched over to the gnome greeter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appear to be two resolutions to this problem. The first is documented in the answer linked above. The second is a little more obscure, but actually resolved my issue.

The first solution is to append `nvidia-drm.modeset=1` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` (`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`). Then save and `sudo update-grub`, ending with a reboot (`shutdown -r now`).

This, like for a few others on that post, did not work for me.

The second solution and & the resolution to my problem was instead scooped from [antechdesigns](https://antechdesigns.000webhostapp.com/wallpaper-fix-for-nvidia-non-free-driver/) who directs you to check for the directory /var/cache/image-blur/ for a blank image (mine was a png). Remove it from this directory. Immediately, I was able to lock my screen and no longer see a white abyss staring me back in the face!

Hope this helps someone as stuck as I was!