# 18.04 nvidia graphics issues with gnome login

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, gnome, login

I am having issues with nvidia drivers in 18.04. I am running Linux 5.0.0-37 on an i7 with GTX 1060 with stock Gnome desktop.

I am currently using the nouveau driver and am able to login and things are working okay, but if I try to install the nvidia drivers (any of the available ones: 390, 410, 415, 430, 435, 440), I am unable to successfully login to the gnome desktop, it just sits at a purple screen. To recover, I need to switch to terminal and purge the nvidia installs.

I see no errors in dmesg when I am unable to login. The nouveau driver works fine for general use, but I cannot play any of my Steam games with it. Any ideas on why **all** of the nvidia drivers would be causing this issue or how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Did you check the recommended Nvidia driver with `ubuntu-drivers device`? Have you tried something else?, maybe this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048274/

Comment: The recommended driver is the 440, which I did install. Thanks for the link. I will try enabling the DRM KMS and report back...

Comment: adding `nvidia-drm.modeset=1` did not resolve my issue.

Comment: In that case, does `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` confirm that the nvidia driver is in use?

Comment: It did show the nvidia driver as the active.

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem, but I did a fresh format and reinstall of 18.04.3, then installed the nvidia 440 driver and am not having any issues now.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem similar to that with a Lenovo p52. I use Debian stretch and it is terrible to manage hybrid video card (change between onboard and offboard) The solution was to disable discrete drive into the bios.