# NMI Watchdog: BUG: soft lockup

Tags: shutdown, cpu

Have had Ubuntu 16.04 on my new machine for about 4-5 months now (ever since I bought it).

Today when shutting down, it generated a message which said:

```
NMI Watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 22s! [swapper/0:0]
```

Can someone please help me get to the bottom of this?

My laptop is still in warranty, and if there is any hardware issue, maybe I can get it replaced right now. Not too worried about software bugs, but of course would like to have this rectified in any case.

Please let me know about any additional information which might be needed.

Answer (score 2):

This is a recurring kernel bug related to nouveau driver

To see if this is this cause, get the GRUB menu at boot time by pressing <kbd>shift</kbd> or maybe <kbd>esc</kbd> repeatedly immediately after switching the machine on. When the menu appears, press the <kbd>e</kbd> key to get the GRUB editor.

Move the cursor to the line that starts with `linux` and to the end of the line. Append `nouveau.modeset=0`, then press <kbd>F10</kbd> to continue to boot.

Log in to your user session, then try to reboot the computer to see if the problem is gone.

If the problem is gone, you can make the change permanent by passing this kernel boot parameter every time, by editing GRUB's config file:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Append `nouveau.modeset=0` after the other words inside the quotes at the end of the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="..."
```

Then to make the change effective, run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Related to [NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 23s! [nvidia-smi:566]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929817/nmi-watchdog-bug-soft-lockup-cpu2-stuck-for-23s-nvidia-smi566)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent errors with watchdog you can disable it:

```
sudo sysctl kernel.nmi_watchdog=0
sudo sysctl kernel.watchdog=0
sudo sysctl kernel.soft_watchdog=0
```