# NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 23s! [nvidia-smi:566]

Tags: boot, nvidia

I installed Xubuntu xfce 16.04, everything was fine, the boot time was about 10 sec, but I could not play games. Then I installed nvidia drivers (I have GTX950, and monitor 2560x1080), it would only boot on recovery mode (just entered and resumed). So I made this modification on grub:

```
/etc/default/grub  
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX="keep"  
GRUB_GFXMODE="1920x1080x32"
```

After that, it boots, but it takes so much time... the screen freezes at the line:

```
 Starting File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/d6e1f5fa-e0e8-455f-8888-268ce02d3a9d...
 Starting File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/322B-518B...
[OK] Started File System Check Daemon to report status.
_
```

After about 25sec I got a Beep sound, then it resumes and the login screen shows up. I have no problem after that.

Below is the journalctl:

```
-- Logs begin at Qua 2017-06-28 08:13:58 AMT, end at Qua 2017-06-28 17:17:01 AMT. --
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk systemd-journald[261]: Runtime journal (/run/log/journal/) is 8.0M, max 78.4M, 70.4M free.
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: Linux version 4.8.0-56-generic (buildd@lcy01-33) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ) #61~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 14 11:58:22 UTC 2017 (Ubuntu 4.8.0-56.61~16.04.1-generic 4.8.17)
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-56-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=aadba17f-3ae3-489a-9278-7314f985f55c ro
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: KERNEL supported cpus:
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel:   Intel GenuineIntel
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel:   AMD AuthenticAMD
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel:   Centaur CentaurHauls
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers'
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[2]:  576, xstate_sizes[2]:  256
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: x86/fpu: Enabled xstate features 0x7, context size is 832 bytes, using 'standard' format.
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: x86/fpu: Using 'eager' FPU context switches.
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
[...]
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: efi: EFI v2.31 by American Megatrends
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: efi:  ACPI 2.0=0xc8f9c000  ACPI=0xc8f9c000  SMBIOS=0xf04c0  MPS=0xfd450 
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: SMBIOS 2.7 present.
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: DMI: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. H97M-D3H/H97M-D3H, BIOS F7 08/03/2015
[...]
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-56-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=aadba17f-3ae3-489a-9278-7314f985f55c ro
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: Calgary: detecting Calgary via BIOS EBDA area
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: Calgary: Unable to locate Rio Grande table in EBDA - bailing!
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: Memory: 7778412K/8250420K available (8829K kernel code, 1441K rwdata, 3836K rodata, 1552K init, 1296K bss, 472008K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=4, Nodes=1
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: Hierarchical RCU implementation.
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel:         Build-time adjustment of leaf fanout to 64.
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel:         RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=512 to nr_cpu_ids=4.
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: RCU: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=64, nr_cpu_ids=4
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: NR_IRQS:33024 nr_irqs:456 16
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: Console: colour dummy device 80x25
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: console [tty0] enabled
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: clocksource: hpet: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 133484882848 ns
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: hpet clockevent registered
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: tsc: Fast TSC calibration using PIT
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: tsc: Detected 3092.965 MHz processor
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 6185.93 BogoMIPS (lpj=12371860)
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: ACPI: Core revision 20160422
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: ACPI: 6 ACPI AML tables successfully acquired and loaded
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: 
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: Security Framework initialized
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: Yama: becoming mindful.
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: AppArmor: AppArmor initialized
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: Dentry cache hash table entries: 1048576 (order: 11, 8388608 bytes)
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: Inode-cache hash table entries: 524288 (order: 10, 4194304 bytes)
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: Mount-cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: CPU: Physical Processor ID: 0
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: CPU: Processor Core ID: 0
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: mce: CPU supports 9 MCE banks
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: CPU0: Thermal monitoring enabled (TM1)
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: process: using mwait in idle threads
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: Last level iTLB entries: 4KB 1024, 2MB 1024, 4MB 1024
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: Last level dTLB entries: 4KB 1024, 2MB 1024, 4MB 1024, 1GB 4
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: Freeing SMP alternatives memory: 32K (ffffffff8aeee000 - ffffffff8aef6000)
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: ftrace: allocating 33462 entries in 131 pages
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: smpboot: APIC(0) Converting physical 0 to logical package 0
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: smpboot: Max logical packages: 1
[...]
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: pci 0000:01:00.0: Video device with shadowed ROM at [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff]
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: PCI: CLS 64 bytes, default 64
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: Unpacking initramfs...
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: Freeing initrd memory: 46720K (ffff9399b24b0000 - ffff9399b5250000)
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: PCI-DMA: Using software bounce buffering for IO (SWIOTLB)
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: software IO TLB [mem 0xb7cde000-0xbbcde000] (64MB) mapped at [ffff939a37cde000-ffff939a3bcddfff]
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: Scanning for low memory corruption every 60 seconds
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: futex hash table entries: 1024 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: audit: type=2000 audit(1498652036.756:1): initialized
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: Initialise system trusted keyrings
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: workingset: timestamp_bits=40 max_order=21 bucket_order=0
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: zbud: loaded
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: squashfs: version 4.0 (2009/01/31) Phillip Lougher
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: fuse init (API version 7.25)
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: Allocating IMA blacklist keyring.
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: Key type asymmetric registered
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 248)
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: io scheduler noop registered
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: io scheduler deadline registered (default)
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: io scheduler cfq registered
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: pci_hotplug: PCI Hot Plug PCI Core version: 0.5
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: pciehp: PCI Express Hot Plug Controller Driver version: 0.4
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: efifb: probing for efifb
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: efifb: framebuffer at 0xf1000000, using 8128k, total 8128k
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: efifb: mode is 1920x1080x32, linelength=7680, pages=1
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: efifb: scrolling: redraw
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: efifb: Truecolor: size=8:8:8:8, shift=24:16:8:0
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: fb0: EFI VGA frame buffer device
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: intel_idle: MWAIT substates: 0x42120
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: intel_idle: v0.4.1 model 0x3C
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: intel_idle: lapic_timer_reliable_states 0xffffffff
[...]
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: microcode: sig=0x306c3, pf=0x2, revision=0x1c
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.01 <tigran@aivazian.fsnet.co.uk>, Peter Oruba
[...]
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[...]
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[...]
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 246
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:01:00.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  381.22  Thu May  4 00:55:03 PDT 2017 (using threaded interrupts)
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  381.22  Thu May  4 00:21:48 PDT 2017
Jun 28 08:13:58 wilhovisk kernel: [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Loading driver
[...]
Jun 28 08:13:59 wilhovisk systemd[1]: Found device SanDisk_SDSSDA120G silver-cloud.
Jun 28 08:13:59 wilhovisk ureadahead[264]: ureadahead:/home/wilhovisk/.cache/xfce4-notifyd-theme.rc: No such file or directory
Jun 28 08:13:59 wilhovisk kernel: input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card2/input22
Jun 28 08:13:59 wilhovisk kernel: input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card2/input23
Jun 28 08:13:59 wilhovisk kernel: input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card2/input24
Jun 28 08:13:59 wilhovisk kernel: input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card2/input25
Jun 28 08:13:59 wilhovisk kernel: clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
Jun 28 08:13:59 wilhovisk systemd[1]: Found device SanDisk_SDSSDA120G 1.
Jun 28 08:13:59 wilhovisk systemd[1]: Starting File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/322B-518B...
Jun 28 08:13:59 wilhovisk systemd[1]: Starting File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/d6e1f5fa-e0e8-455f-8888-268ce02d3a9d...
Jun 28 08:13:59 wilhovisk systemd[1]: Started File System Check Daemon to report status.
Jun 28 08:13:59 wilhovisk systemd-fsck[596]: silver-cloud: clean, 5480/603840 files, 1037656/2413056 blocks
Jun 28 08:13:59 wilhovisk systemd[1]: Started File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/d6e1f5fa-e0e8-455f-8888-268ce02d3a9d.
Jun 28 08:13:59 wilhovisk systemd[1]: Mounting /media/wilhovisk/SSD-silver-cloud...
Jun 28 08:13:59 wilhovisk kernel: NVRM: Your system is not currently configured to drive a VGA console
Jun 28 08:13:59 wilhovisk kernel: NVRM: on the primary VGA device. The NVIDIA Linux graphics driver
Jun 28 08:13:59 wilhovisk kernel: NVRM: requires the use of a text-mode VGA console. Use of other console
Jun 28 08:13:59 wilhovisk kernel: NVRM: drivers including, but not limited to, vesafb, may result in
Jun 28 08:13:59 wilhovisk kernel: NVRM: corruption and stability problems, and is not supported.
Jun 28 08:13:59 wilhovisk systemd-fsck[595]: fsck.fat 3.0.28 (2015-05-16)
Jun 28 08:13:59 wilhovisk systemd-fsck[595]: /dev/sda1: 8 files, 6890/286310 clusters
Jun 28 08:13:59 wilhovisk systemd[1]: Started File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/322B-518B.
Jun 28 08:13:59 wilhovisk systemd[1]: Mounting /boot/efi...
Jun 28 08:14:25 wilhovisk kernel: EXT4-fs (sda3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: errors=remount-ro
Jun 28 08:14:25 wilhovisk kernel: usb 3-9: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Jun 28 08:14:25 wilhovisk kernel: ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_set_rt: Info - RT chipset 5392, rev 0223 detected
Jun 28 08:14:25 wilhovisk kernel: ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_set_rf: Info - RF chipset 5372 detected
Jun 28 08:14:25 wilhovisk kernel: ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
Jun 28 08:14:25 wilhovisk kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver rt2800usb
Jun 28 08:14:25 wilhovisk kernel: rt2800usb 3-9:1.0 wlx001a3fd2ebb4: renamed from wlan0
Jun 28 08:14:25 wilhovisk kernel: NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 23s! [nvidia-smi:555]
Jun 28 08:14:25 wilhovisk kernel: Modules linked in: arc4 rt2800usb rt2x00usb rt2800lib rt2x00lib mac80211 cfg80211 nvidia_uvm(POE) joydev input_leds intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd intel_cstate snd_hda_codec_hdmi intel_rapl_perf snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic serio_raw snd_soc_rt5640 lpc_ich snd_hda_intel mei_me snd_hda_codec mei snd_soc_ssm4567 snd_soc_rl6231 snd_soc_core snd_hda_core shpchp snd_hwdep snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer snd snd_soc_sst_acpi snd_soc_sst_match dw_dmac soundcore elan_i2c dw_dmac_core mac_hid i2c_designware_platform tpm_infineon spi_pxa2xx_platform
Jun 28 08:14:25 wilhovisk kernel:  i2c_designware_core 8250_dw acpi_pad parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log hid_generic usbhid i915 nvidia_drm(POE) nvidia_modeset(POE) i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt nvidia(POE) fb_sys_fops psmouse ahci libahci drm video fjes i2c_hid sdhci_acpi hid sdhci
Jun 28 08:14:25 wilhovisk kernel: CPU: 0 PID: 555 Comm: nvidia-smi Tainted: P           OE   4.8.0-56-generic #61~16.04.1-Ubuntu
Jun 28 08:14:25 wilhovisk kernel: Hardware name: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. H97M-D3H/H97M-D3H, BIOS F7 08/03/2015
Jun 28 08:14:25 wilhovisk kernel: task: ffff939b9b47d880 task.stack: ffff939ba1770000
Jun 28 08:14:25 wilhovisk kernel: RIP: 0010:[<ffffffffc043b9fc>]  [<ffffffffc043b9fc>] os_io_read_dword+0xc/0x10 [nvidia]
[...]
```

this is the systemd-analyze blame:

```
     25.844s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-322B\x2d518B.service
      1.444s dev-sda2.device
       519ms NetworkManager-wait-online.service
       204ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-d6e1f5fa\x2de0e8\x2d455f\x2d8888\x2d268ce02d3a9d.service
       165ms systemd-modules-load.service
       129ms accounts-daemon.service
       120ms keyboard-setup.service
       113ms networking.service
       110ms ModemManager.service
       104ms NetworkManager.service
        95ms grub-common.service
        94ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
        83ms systemd-journald.service
        78ms upower.service
        78ms gpu-manager.service
        74ms systemd-logind.service
        73ms apparmor.service
        59ms lightdm.service
        58ms ondemand.service
        52ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
        51ms thermald.service
        50ms speech-dispatcher.service
        50ms console-setup.service
        49ms irqbalance.service
        48ms apport.service
        46ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
        45ms resolvconf.service
        39ms lm-sensors.service
        35ms snapd.socket
        32ms ufw.service
        28ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
        27ms systemd-timesyncd.service
        25ms dev-hugepages.mount
        25ms dev-mqueue.mount
        23ms systemd-journal-flush.service
        22ms polkitd.service
        21ms systemd-udevd.service
        21ms systemd-rfkill.service
        19ms avahi-daemon.service
        19ms kmod-static-nodes.service
        16ms rsyslog.service
        16ms udisks2.service
        14ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
        12ms user@108.service
        12ms alsa-restore.service
        12ms binfmt-support.service
        12ms plymouth-read-write.service
        12ms systemd-update-utmp.service
        11ms snapd.autoimport.service
        11ms boot-efi.mount
        10ms wpa_supplicant.service
        10ms user@1000.service
         9ms systemd-user-sessions.service
         8ms pppd-dns.service
         8ms systemd-sysctl.service
         8ms systemd-remount-fs.service
         7ms systemd-hostnamed.service
         5ms media-wilhovisk-SSD\x2dsilver\x2dcloud.mount
         5ms hddtemp.service
         4ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
         3ms systemd-random-seed.service
         3ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
         2ms setvtrgb.service
         2ms rtkit-daemon.service
         2ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
         2ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         1ms nvidia-persistenced.service
         1ms rc-local.service
```

This is my fstab, I copied the entry for the root /, and replace "/" for the "/media/wilhovisk/SSD-silver-cloud", maybe there is too much space after the mount point. Can I delete the spaces and hit one time tab key?

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=aadba17f-3ae3-489a-9278-7314f985f55c /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=322B-518B  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       2
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=d6e1f5fa-e0e8-455f-8888-268ce02d3a9d /media/wilhovisk/SSD-silver-cloud               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       2
```

How can this be solved? I can post other reports here, just say what I have to post that can be useful to resolve this bug.

Thank you.

Comment: That's much better... `systemd-fsck` taking so long... I wonder why that is happening at all! Hopefully someone knows... I'll search for it

Comment: how do I add that is solved? Here is what solved to me: I saw this post by Laurent85, at https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=231558, he said to try "At startup edit the Grub menu entry and append kernel parameter nomodeset or modprobe.blacklist=nouveau to existing parameters quiet splash". So I entered terminal, sudo thunar, went to /etc/default/grub, and edited this line to this GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset". After, went to the terminal: sudo update-grub. Thats it, 8 seconds the boot time, no beep sound, I am so happy, no cpu stuck on the journalctl anymore! :)

Comment: Ah that's good, you can write it as an answer for your question and accept the answer after a couple of days, but maybe `nomodeset` has some side effects you don't like? Surprised that fixes it!

Comment: Its been a while, its still good maybe there is some side effects but I could not perceive them. What could it be? Thank you for the help, its my first request on this askubuntu.

Comment: Issues with graphics. But if it's ok for you, that's great

Answer (score 20):

Here is what solved it for me: I saw [this post on Linux Mint Forums](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=231558) and followed the advice of Laurent85:

> At startup edit the Grub menu entry and append kernel parameter `nomodeset` or `modprobe.blacklist=nouveau` to existing parameters `quiet splash`".

So I edited the file `/etc/default/grub`, and edited the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line to this

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset".
```

Afterwards I ran `sudo update-grub`. Thats it, 8 seconds the boot time, no beep sound, I am so happy, no CPU stuck on `journalctl` anymore! :)

**Warning!** Adding `nomodeset` permanently to `/etc/default/grub` will disable Nvidia drivers. This option is useful only if the system doesn't boot correctly with `nouveau`. After you install Nvidia drivers, this parameter should be removed.

Comment: modprobe.blacklist=nouveau was all i needed.

Comment: There is one detail I like to add, my problem were in the Ubuntu 18 install. To me adding the `modprobe.blacklist=nouveau` solved the problem but there were a catch, at the end of the line (linux command) like `linux ..... quiet splash ---` there were those three dashes and my only worked after I removed then, so in the end `linux ..... quiet splash modprobe.blacklist=nouveau` \o/ Thanks bro! brand new powerful notebook that was just a doorstop before this post xD

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 with an Nvidia 8400 GS card. after I installed the recommended, tested, proprietary Nvidia driver v.340-104. via Additional Drivers. My solution begins with a similar approach as [this answer] but ends somewhat differently.

1) At startup edit the Grub menu entry and append kernel parameter nomodeset to existing parameters quiet splash.

2) Revert back to the nouveau driver via Additional drivers.

**Note:** If you installed nvidia drivers via some other method you may need to purge them following steps [1 and 2 here](https://askubuntu.com/a/481540/225694) **skipping the line** `blacklist nouveau` in step 1.

3) Reboot.

Boot time is respectable for an old Intel E6500 Dual Core without an SSD.