# Fresh install of Kubuntu 17.10 beeps after installing NVidia driver

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, kubuntu

I've just installed Kubuntu 17.10 on my PC without problems. It installed fined, booted fine and updated fine. Next stop was activating the privative drivers for my NVidia GTX 1060 using the *Drivers* panel in the settings. It autoinstalled the drivers seemingly without issue.

Now everytime it boots, there're a couple of issues. **After** the GRUB, the loading screen with Kubuntu logo appears on screen with a very low resolution and after a couple of seconds the motherboard speaker **beeps**, just as it does on POST. Several seconds pass and the Plasma loading screen appears, finally revealing the desktop after some more time.

The startup time with the NVidia drivers installed is much longer than with the default drivers (nouveau). I've tried manually installing the latest drivers from the repo (`nvidia-390` package), with the same results. I've also tried using the bundled drivers from the NVidia website, and it failed miserably (*"Plasma is unable to start as it could not correctly use OpenGL 2"*, but that's a different issue).

What could be the problem? My motherboard has an integrated Intel graphics card if that's of any help.

Answer (score 1):

After checking `dmesg` I saw the *halt point* in the boot process:

```
[    3.572204] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno1: link is not ready
[   28.060038] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 23s! [nvidia-smi:471]
```

I searched for that error message and landed on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/934850/26960), which suggested adding `nomodeset` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in the grub settings file.

It worked flawlessly!