# Watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#4 stuck for 22s!

Tags: system-installation, 18.04

My laptop is an Acer Aspire 3 a315-41g-r4bw. I tried to install  Ubuntu-desktop 18.04 via usb. But it  stucks for hours  with following error code

```
Watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#4
```

I cannot  click or type anything!

How to stop this?

Comment: Press`Ctrl`+`C` together. If that doesn't work hold down power button for 10 seconds and hope everything will turn out ok later.

Comment: If you are continuously getting that issue, I suggest you do a google search. I found many posts relating to the error, in some cases adding a nomodeset kernel parameter solved it, but I saw a lot of different scenarios causing it. I've seen a post where someone replaced their PSU which solved it as it was caused by weak power draw on the cpu!!! The point is that this can be caused by many factors, but I suspect and hope a nomodeset will probably solve it for you as you are doing an install.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 23s! \[nvidia-smi:566\]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929817/nmi-watchdog-bug-soft-lockup-cpu2-stuck-for-23s-nvidia-smi566)

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have exactly the same problem with my acer.

You can try the steps below:

1. Turn off the AMD settings on the 'Advanced' tab on the BIOS.
2. When installing ubuntu, highlight the 'install ubuntu' selection and press e.
3. Go to the line with 'linux' and at the end put space and add 'pci=noacpi'
4. Press F10 and the installation process will begin.

Hope it works out for you!