# What does modprobe.blacklist=nouveau do?

Tags: drivers, grub2, nouveau

I just blacklisted nouveau, but I see that it is still being used. Would someone please help me understand this?

My new installation of 18.10 would freeze when logging in. To resolve this, I blacklisted nouveau in grub by updating `/etc/default/grub` with

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash modprobe.blacklist=nouveau"
```

(The solution was from [NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 23s!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929817/nmi-watchdog-bug-soft-lockup-cpu2-stuck-for-23s-nvidia-smi566/934850#934850), which was the issue had I experienced.)

I am glad that I am now able to successfully login, but I see that Nouveau is still being used, and this is confusing.

I thought I just blacklisted it, so why do I see it as active in Software and Updates?

What does the line `modprobe.blacklist=nouveau` exactly do? (Perhaps I misunderstand it).

Are there any disadvantages of adding `modprobe.blacklist=nouveau` to grub?

[image]

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/831297/15811 has all you ask for.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, there is a conflict between the open-source driver with that of the graphic card from Nvidia. I will write down the solution that worked for me, on a Lenovo ThinkPad P53 when installing Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, I faced some issues.

Follow the steps written below:

1. Boot to Ubuntu, but before you login in to Ubuntu, press Cntrl+Alt+F2
2. run the following command:

   ```
        sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf
   ```
3. add the 2 following lines, save & exit

   ```
        blacklist nouveau
        options nouveau modeset=0
   ```
4. run the following command

   ```
        sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```