# Ubuntu 18.10: Troubles with NVIDIA Drivers "Nvidia X Server (Control Panel) displays an empty window"

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, brightness

I've just switched from Mint to try Ubuntu and had a lot of problems with installing it. I managed to launch Ubuntu in tty and change my grub adding

```
nomodeset
```

to the grub config file...

Now i'm having problems with my desktop animations (there are no animations), screen brightness (iam unable to adjust it) and Nvidia Control Panel (its empty window with no info)

--> [image: nvidia window]. So, I don't know what to do...

System info: 
Asus GL753VD
Ubuntu 18.10
Intel® Core™ i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz × 8 
Graphics: llvmpipe (LLVM 7.0, 256 bits)
Graphic Card: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]
Im using Nvidia 415 Driver.

Thank you!

p.s. it is a little bit strange that Mint is based on Ubuntu and i had literally no problems with it (except its Gui)

```
lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 591b (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1590
    Kernel modules: i915
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 59)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: `nomodeset` kinda by definition disables your video drivers.  It's mostly used to get the system to boot, then install the drivers.  After a successful driver install, you should remove it.

Comment: Lately lots of people have this problem. Probably they found some popular manual with nomodeset.

Comment: @OrganicMarble so i have to remove "nomodeset" and type: "nouveau.modeset=0"?

Comment: Just remove `nomodeset` and run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: I use a GTX 1050 Ti (desktop) and run the 390 driver. I don't have any reference to `nomodeset` in my grub at all.

Comment: `nomodeset` is needed to boot with `nouveau` sometimes. But I see no reason to set it permanently in `/etc/default/grub`. Can OP tell us where did he get this manual?

Comment: Actually; there are 2 manuals:[first](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747314/is-nomodeset-still-required) and [second](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929817/nmi-watchdog-bug-soft-lockup-cpu2-stuck-for-23s-nvidia-smi566)