# I'm trying to install ubuntu 18.04

Tags: system-installation, cpu

I'm trying to install ubuntu on my laptop. It's an asus.
Here are the specs:
[image: specs]
I've desactivated the fast and secureboot.
I use a cd to install ubuntu.(it works,my father installed it on his pc)
But i have this error :

```
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#4 stuck for 23s! [thermald:1424]
```

It keep sending this message with the different cpu numbers.
Someone can help me find the origin of the issue ?

Comment: Possibly disabling nvidia drivers as described in [https://askubuntu.com/a/934850/283721](https://askubuntu.com/a/934850/283721)

Comment: Also see [How to install Ubuntu on Asus f556u journalerror error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079540/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-asus-f556u-journalerror-error)

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be the NVIDIA drivers.

See this post + answer for troubleshooting:
[NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 23s! [nvidia-smi:566]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929817/nmi-watchdog-bug-soft-lockup-cpu2-stuck-for-23s-nvidia-smi566) and
https://askubuntu.com/a/934850/949723:

At startup, edit the Grub menu entry and append the kernel parameter "nomodeset" or `modprobe.blacklist=nouveau` to the existing parameters `quiet splash`.

So I edited the file /etc/default/grub, and edited the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line to this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
```

Afterwards I ran `sudo update-grub`. That's it, 8 seconds the boot time, no beep sound, I am so happy, no CPU stuck on `journalctl` anymore! :)

Warning! Adding "nomodeset" permanently to `/etc/default/grub` will disable NVidia drivers. This option is useful only if the system doesn't boot correctly with Nouveau.

**After you install the NVidia drivers, this parameter should be removed**.