# No way of getting Nvidia GPU activated on Ubuntu 17

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, nvidia-optimus, gpu

At the moment, my Dell XPS 15 9560 which runs Ubuntu 17 is using the intel CPU's built in GPU. I have made many attempts to change this, so that it uses the GTX 1050.

I gather I need nivida-settings to work. Right now, after installation, I get the following error when trying to run it:

```
ERROR: Unable to find display on any available system
```

Apparently this is because certain changes in Ubuntu 17 (involving Wayland) no longer allow nvidia-settings to run.

A solution to this was to try logging in to my account as "Xorg Ubuntu", this just froze my computer, requiring reboot.

I have also tried installing nvidia drivers from online, and using bumblebee. In both these cases, it broke my OS. After installation, I would reboot, and get a console output that was essentially inescapable (many lines of this kind of thing: `[ OK ] starting network manager`). Other people have experienced this, with no known solution (no reboot/startup bios tricks). I had to reinstall Ubuntu completely. I am now extremely reluctant to install any driver related programs online or through apt-get, considering all attempts resulted in breaking the OS.

I have also looked at the Additional Drivers section of Software & Updates which contained two rows:

```
Using NVIDIA binary driver - version 384 from nvidia-384 (proprietary)
(selected) Using X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver from xserver...etc
```

Having tried both, neither made a difference to nvidia-settings working, or changing the GPU.

**There must be a simple, intuitive way to switch GPU on Ubuntu 17**, but I keep hitting dead ends. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're using 17.10, correct?  Maybe look into https://askubuntu.com/a/747429/231142 for nomodeset when using XOrg.

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04 is off-topic because it is EOL (End of Life). Ubuntu 17.10 will also be EOL soon (July).  You would be better served by Ubuntu 16.04 LTS or possibly 18.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

after fresh installation i added repo:
http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1704/x86_64

Than in synaptic (because i forgot which 2 I installed) select **nvidia-cuda**, nvidia-dkms-390, nvidia-compute-utils-390, nvidia-utils-390, **nvidia-driver-390** nvidia-prime, nvidia-setting, xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390.

(now is 06/2018)

- now 2 important remarks :)
- 1. Is NV listed in system ? (not disabled in Bios or disable intel vga, make NV primary)
- 2. Wayland not support current nvdrivers drivers so don't use WYL.

Comment: installing nvidia-driver-390 is exactly what broke my system. 1. Yes, the graphics card is listed in the system. 2. As I described, the alternative to Wayland does not work (Xorg)