# No GUI after Login, GUI works if I drop into TTY terminal then back to lightDM

Tags: xubuntu, login, lightdm, xfce, gui

Just installed Xubuntu 18.04 on my HP Pavilion 15 in a dual boot configuration with windows. I was running Gnomebuntu 16.04 previously, but I am now unable to either install any distro or get the selected GUI to run (tried Debian, Ubuntu, Manjaro with lxde, xfce, kde). It will either not login or site with just the wallpaper and mouse. Any and all help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It was a nomodeset issue with Nvidia drivers. One can find the solution here

[Is nomodeset still required?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747314/is-nomodeset-still-required)