# Cannot seem to get 18.04 to install on HD of PC

Tags: usb

I am trying to get Ubuntu 18.04.2 installed on a bootable DVD or USB Drive.

I downloaded the ISO of 18.04.2 just fine.

Here are the problems I am having:
1) I changed the boot order of my BIOS to the USB drive first.  Then I saved and let it go on.  It immediately turned black and would not come back even if I let it go overnight.
2) Then I tried doing the same thing with the DVD.  It did the same thing after I changed the boot order to DVD, then let it go on.
3) Finally, I tried putting another HD in the PC and did the same thing (with the USB) and it did the same thing.

I have had Ubuntu 16.04 on the PC before.  It originally was a Windows 8/10 box before I re purposed it to Linux so I know it should work for 18.04.  I am pulling my hair out trying to get this turned to Ubuntu 18.04.

The PC is as follows:
ASUS M Series M51AC
Intel Core i7 (4th Gen) 4770 / 3.4 GHz
16 GB RAM
1 TB Hard Drive

Please give me a hand getting this converted to 18.04!  I am not trying to dual-boot, I am just trying to get the newest LTS version of Ubuntu put on it.

Thank You,
Mike

Comment: You downloaded the ISO 'just fine' (so I take it you md5sum validated it etc).  Did you verify the write the thumb-drive (which you are trying to boot from), ie. boot on another machine or that machine & perform 'media-check' to ensure the write-to-install-media was valid.  If you can't do this on that system, I'd suggest performing it on another pc/laptop to confirm your install media is correct & your issue is the machine you're trying to boot & install on.

Answer (score 0):

According to a [Google search](https://www.cnet.com/products/asus-m-series-m51ac-tower-core-i7-4770-3-4-ghz-16-gb-1-tb/) your computer probably uses an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 760. Most of the black screen issues from Nvidia is because there needs to be [`nouveau.modeset=0`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747314/is-nomodeset-still-required) added to GRUB to boot. You can add it to yours by pressing esc right when it boots up but only once. Then you should see a menu where you press e to edit.

The line in particular to change:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash **nouveau.modeset=0**"

Once you've installed you need to do it again when booting into the system and add edit it for the final time so that it's a default boot mode.