# Webcam Problems Ubuntu 20.04 - DELL G3 3579

Tags: drivers, 20.04, dell, webcam

I have a G3 3579 and i have installed Ubuntu 20.04.
At the beginning there were some problems as the laptop time to time used to freeze, but everything is solved by setting nomodeset.

Now I am having problems with my WebCam as it isn't recognized at all.

Does anyone had this kind of problem?
How did you managed to resolve it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to get the webcam working in Windows 10. You might find new drivers need to be installed from Dell:

- [Find a driver for your Dell G3 3579](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-ca/product-support/product/g-series-15-3579-laptop/drivers)

After drivers have been updated in Windows 10, then you can focus on getting Ubuntu working. The first step though should be to fix your graphics mode setting errors that require you to use `nomodeset`. One possible cause can be found at:

- [Is nomodeset still required?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747314/is-nomodeset-still-required)

Comment: In windows camera works perfectly. The problem is that Dell doesn't have drivers for ubuntu for this laptop model.

Comment: @ZenelRrushi When you update firmware for webcam using Windows 10 drivers it helps out Ubuntu too. Now that we know Windows 10 is working fine, it's time to fix the `nomodeset` problem. After all the known problems are fixed the webcam will hopefully be fixed with it.