# Ubuntu stuck on boot, won't get past on file and blocks

Tags: boot, 20.04, intel-graphics

**I do not use Nvidia Driver**

I am stuck on this screen when I boot up Ubuntu.

Info about my computer:

- Intel CPU Core i7-6700K
- Intel(R) HD Graphics 530

  - GPU is Skylate GT2
  - Subvendor: ASRock
  - Multi-GPU is disabled

I've looked online here, and used methods, like using `nomodeset` when booting up, but that didn't work either. I've also tried something like removing nvidia using the `sudo` command but I don't even know because I don't use a nvidia driver.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

[Bootup Screen Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAkQG.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)

Comment: No, that is Nvidia driver. I explicitly stated that it is not that I am using Intel. I already purged and followed most of the answers and posts in this website but none of them worked.

Comment: That's just one of the answers. What are you going to do, disqualify all the other answers to that question because of that one answer that didn't solve your question?

Comment: No, I already look at other posts about this too, not just this one.

Comment: Have you added `nouveau.modeset=0` as a kernel boot parameter? I'm not sure what your distro and kernel version are, but the former is used nowadays moreso than `nodemodeset`. It disables less features than nomodeset according to https://askubuntu.com/questions/747314/is-nomodeset-still-required

Comment: @lolsky The post's answer including nvidia, I'm not using a nvidia driver, i'm using intel

Comment: Adding that boot parameter will ensure that the kernel does not try to load your video driver. Instead the display manager (like GNOME, KDE) will do it. It does not specifically try to load one from Nvidia. Have you tried it and gotten the same result?

Comment: @lolsky The answer is saying to install nvidia and I'm not using nvidia.