# Errors after reboot from fresh installation on laptop

Tags: boot, nvidia, system-installation, 20.04

I just installed Ubuntu Studio on my HP OMEN laptop and it installed successfully and needed to reboot. Once the laptop turned back on I got this set of errors and I'm unsure how
to fix this. This is also the only screen I can see and cannot use my laptop.

```
nvidia-gpu 0000:01:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
ucsi_ccg 1-0008: i2c transfer failed -110 
ucsi_ccg 1-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed - -110
hci0: Failed to send Intel_Write_DDC (-22)
```

Edit: here is the new lines of error on startup
nouveau 0000:1:00.0 fifo SCHED_ERROR 08 []
nouveau 0000:1:00.0 DRM: failed to idle channel 0 [DRM]

Comment: Are you able to switch to tty1(`[Ctrl]`+`[Alt]`+`[F1]`) after seeing this message?

Comment: Yes and I logged in and there are a bunch of errors with nouveau. What should I do next?

Comment: There is a *slight* chance that your desktop environment is broken. Try this: `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: Could you update your question to include those nouveau errors?

Comment: I updated the post and tried to do the install and its unable to locate the ubuntu studio package, unable to locate apt-get package, and install package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I concur with TheCummuter; `nomodeset` may be part of the answer. Have you installed the Nvidia proprietary drivers? If not, try this:

1. Add `nomodeset` to your Grub configuration by [following these steps](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln306327/manual-nomodeset-kernel-boot-line-option-for-linux-booting?lang=en) (this is a Dell support page, but it is the same for most systems)
2. Reboot. Hopefully this will bring you to the desktop.
3. Install [the proprietary drivers via Software & Updates](https://itsfoss.com/install-additional-drivers-ubuntu/)
4. Reboot again.

So long as everything works properly, you should be able to update Grub one more time to remove `nomodeset` and everything will work properly.

Hope this helps

Comment: I did the nomodeset but under the install ubuntu studio and I still have the same screen. Can I install the drivers through the tty1?

Comment: I have never installed video drivers from `tty1`, but [the answer in this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers) might give you the step-by-step to do so.

Comment: Okay so I performed the following commands (I apologize ahead of time for not writing it in code. I'm using my phone to type this) 'nvidia-xconfig' then 'sudo apt install nvidia-utils-455' then sudo apt install nvidia-driver-455' and needs the disk reader but everytime I press enter like it says in the directions it just repeats the same message to put in the disc when I have the USB in

Comment: Hmm ... I can imagine this is quite frustrating for you. Perhaps it would be better to try the second-line drivers from Ubuntu? `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`, then reboot. If this doesn't get you into a GUI, then I'm really not sure how to solve the problem. 

Answer (score 1):

Try following the instructions here: [Is nomodeset still required?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747314/is-nomodeset-still-required)

You may need to hit the ESC key during boot to view the grub menu.